# Video stream from webcam and Sending through websocket and saving into mp4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, websocket

```
private static async Task EchoRecording(HttpContext context, WebSocket webSocket)
    {
        //string path = @"E:\Recording.mp4";
        var path = Path.Combine("wwwroot", "SaveRecord", "Recording.mp4");
        var buffer = new byte[1024 * 8];
        WebSocketReceiveResult result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

        while (!result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append))
                try
                {
                    await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, result.Count);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }

            result = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

        }
        await webSocket.CloseAsync(result.CloseStatus.Value, result.CloseStatusDescription, CancellationToken.None);
    }
```

Stream is saving successfully, But duration and length of video is not saving when viewing.
Should i use anything instead of filestream?

Comment: Why do you have two webSocket.ReceiveAsync()?  Normally you have a Request (send data) and a response (receive data).  So a Websocket the client sends a request and the server returns a response.  So there should be a request and a response before another request and a response.   It looks like you have two response without a request in between.

Comment: ok. but the issue is, when writing stream by using filestream, length of the video is not saving. video is saving without length, duration attributes

Comment: The duration is in the Meta Data of the file which is what you see when you hover over the file with a mouse.  See Page 14 of following : https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flv/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf.  You would need to add the meta data to the file.  The Video has a ASCII header which give into like frame size.  So you can calculate the duration based on the file size and the frame size.